# How to add checkboxes in crosssell.phtml on cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In cross sell product,every product has different add to cart button.But i need checkboxes for every product and single add to cart button,which on clicked the selected product gets added to the cart.
Below is the functionality image i am trying to achieve
[image]

I am new to magento,any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddhant,You need a customization

- First, you need to an add form `<form></from>` which may be  located at
  `app/design/frontend/Your_package/Your_theme/template/checkout/cart/crossell.phtml`
- And add a *`checkbox beside each product`*  and that checkbox name
  should be **dynamic like and sending product id at this field**

> `<input type="checkbox" id="crossell-checkbox<?php echo
>   $_item->getProduct()->getId() ?>"  name="crossell[]" value="<?php echo
>   $_item->getProduct()->getId() ?>" />`

- Then **create a controller** where you would be submit this form and   fetch the `crossell`
  field values and **cart those checked products programmatically**

  > ```
  > $productIds=$this->getRequest()->getParam('crossell');
  > if (!empty($productIds)) {
  >             foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
  >               $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  >               $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
  >               $cart->init();
  >               $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
  >               $cart->save();
  >           }
  > }
  > ```

Comment: What will be the form action url?

Comment: i already told you ,you need to create  create a new module's  with a controller